# How easy (or difficult) is it to migrate to a development environment on Mac from Ubuntu

Tags: django, macos, ubuntu, development-environment

I am used to Ubuntu, I like it, I know my way around it.

I am looking forward to [upgrade my work laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/84495/laptop-with-good-hardware-similar-to-a-macbook-pro).

I find the awesome hardware that a Macbook Pro is made of, a turn-on.

Now, having never used a mac before, I'd like to know how easy it is to move my development environment to a mac from being on Ubuntu.

My work is primarily web application development using the django framework.

I love the apt-get install and the package managers and such stuff that Ubuntu provides. Are there equivalents on a mac?

What are the other things I need to know to move my development environment to a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved from ubuntu to Mac 6 months back, the tools that you get in Mac are awesome(like iweb) and *most* of the application work out of the box without compilation. There are alternative for apt-get in Mac, I use port, fink which works pretty much like apt-get. I would say list down all your favorites tools in ubuntu mostly you will find the same in Mac or its equivalent.

Comment: iWeb is not really a development tool.

Answer (score 2):

Should be pretty easy. [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) is like a package manager for installing open source software and libraries.

I do some django work and moved from Windows to Mac recently. I found it very easy since django is Python which is pre-installed in Mac OS X, but can be upgraded if necessary. I also use Eclipse with the PyDev plugin which all runs on Java.